# NDSolve initial value not explicitly specified

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve for 2 first order coupled ODEs. I've got two initial conditions, and I can't get a solution. I've double checked my equation input and my initial conditions, and my NDSolve function looks similar to the example posted in the documentation so I'm stumped. Here's what I've got going:

```
gamma := 0;
Ra := 2.32 * 10^9;
Ja :=  0.315;
C1 :=  .5;
C2 := .6666;
qdotc := 1;
C3 := .75;


sol = NDSolve[
   {delta'[t] == 
     C1 * Ja * (1 + gamma * delta[t]) / (delta[t]^3 * Ra * Sin[t]) - 
      C2 * (delta[t]) * Cot[t],
    q'[t] == 1/ delta[t] * Sin[t],
    delta[0] == 0.00317666163538945,
    q[0] == 0
    },
   {delta, q},
   {t, 0, 1},
   Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", 
     Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", Automatic}}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 100][[1, 1]]

Plot[Evaluate[delta[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

And then I get the following error messages:

[image]

Comment: Your ode -system is of order 1 , though your initial condition `q'[0]== 0` isn't allowed!

Comment: The precision issue is because you are using approximate numbers, and then trying to specify WorkingPrecision to be 100. The second error is because $cot(0)$ is a divide by zero error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gamma = 0;
Ra = 232*10^7;
Ja = 315/1000;
C1 = 1/2;
C2 = 6666/10000;
qdotc = 1;
C3 = 75/100;
t0 = 10^-5;
q0 = Rationalize[0.00317666163538945];
sol = NDSolve[{delta'[t] == 
    C1*Ja*(1 + gamma*delta[t])/(delta[t]^3*Ra*Sin[t]) - 
     C2*(delta[t])*Cot[t], q'[t] == 1/delta[t]*Sin[t], 
   delta[t0] == q0, q[t0] == 0}, {delta, q}, {t, t0, 1}]

Plot[Evaluate[delta[t] /. First[sol]], {t, t0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly now.

Comment: You're welcome!